# Find the value of $\sin\frac{19 π}{2}$ using the addition and subtraction trigonometry formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The formula is $\displaystyle\sin(s-t)= \sin(s)\cos(t) - \cos(s)\sin(t)$

$$\sin \frac{19 π}{2}=\sin \left(\frac{21 π}{2} - \frac{2π}{2}\right)$$

I am not sure I know how to convert radians. I would like to find the the difference of $\dfrac{19 π}{2}$. Is there a better way to arrive at radians? Should I be dividing $\dfrac{19 π}{2}$ by something to get the difference in radians? The system I am using seems clumsy.

Comment: An alternative to the addition formula in this case is to note that $\sin(x+\pi/2) =\sin(\pi/2-(-x))=\cos(-x)=\cos x.$

Answer (score 2):

Using the sine difference formula you have,
$$\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{20\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sin(10\pi)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\cos(10\pi)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\=(0\cdot0)-(1\cdot1)=-1$$

Comment: I can see that it works,but how did you figure out that 20π/2 -  π/2 were the difference?

Comment: @user137452 He didn't; he could've picked any two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a-b=19\pi/2$, but $\sin(10\pi)=\sin(2\pi)$ is a well-known value (0).

Comment: As alexqwx has correctly pointed, I did indeed choose $20\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ as their sine and cosine are well known i.e. $\sin(10\pi)=\sin(2\pi)=\cos(\pi/2)=0$ and $\sin(\pi/2)=\cos(10\pi)=\cos(2\pi)=1$ .

Comment: Okay. For example sin(19π/12). How do I figure out (what) - (what) = 19π/12?

Comment: @user137452: the example you give is a bit more involved, and I will evaluate it algebraically. I would use $\sin(19\pi/12)=\sin(2\pi-5\pi/12)=\sin(2\pi)\cos(5\pi/12)-\cos(2\pi)\sin(5\pi/12)=-\sin(5\pi/12)$. Now, $\sin(5\pi/12)=\sin(\pi/2-\pi/12)=\sin(\pi/2)\cos(\pi/12)-\cos(\pi/2)\sin(\pi/12)=\cos(\pi/12)$. So, $\sin(19\pi/12)=-\cos(\pi/12)$. We can further evaluate, as $\cos(\pi/12)=\cos(\pi/3-\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/3)\cos(\pi/4)+\sin(\pi/3)\sin(\pi/4)=(1/2)(1/\sqrt{2})+(\sqrt{3}/2)(1/\sqrt{2})=(1+\sqrt{3})/2\sqrt{2}$. Thus, $\sin(19\pi/12)=-(1+\sqrt{3})/2\sqrt{2}$.